# /usr/bin/env questions regarding shebang line pecularities

Tags: linux, apache, unix, environment, shebang

**Questions**:

- What does the kernel do if you stick a shell-script into the shebang line?
- How does the Kernel know which interpreter to launch?

**Explanation**:

I recently wanted to write a wrapper around */usr/bin/env* because my CGI Environment does not allow me to set the *PATH* variable, except globally (which of course sucks!).

So I thought, "OK. Let's set PREPENDPATH and set *PATH* in a wrapper around env.". The resulting script (here called *env.1*) looked like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/env PATH=$PREPENDPATH:$PATH $*
```

which looks like it should work. I checked how they both react, after setting PREPENDPATH:

```
$ which /usr/bin/env python
/usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/python

$ which /usr/bin/env.1 python
/usr/bin/env
/home/pi/prepend/bin/python
```

Look absolutely *perfect*! So far, so good. But look what happens to "Hello World!".

```
# Shebang is #!/usr/bin/env python
$ test-env.py
Hello World!

# Shebang is #!/usr/bin/env.1 python
$ test-env.1.py
Warning: unknown mime-type for "Hello World!" -- using "application/*"
Error: no such file "Hello World!"
```

I guess I am missing something pretty fundamental about UNIX.

I'm pretty lost, even after looking at the source code of the original *env*. It sets the environment and launches the program (or so it seems to me...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should very seldom use `$*` and you should almost always use `"$@"` instead.  There are a number of questions here on SO which explain the ins and outs of why.

Second - the `env` command has two main uses.  One is to print the current environment; the other is to completely control the environment of a command when it is run.  The third use, which you are demonstrating, is to modify the environment, but frankly there's no need for that - the shells are quite capable of handling that for you.

Mode 1:

```
env
```

Mode 2:

```
env -i HOME=$HOME PATH=$PREPENDPATH:$PATH ... command args
```

This version cancels all inherited environment variables and runs `command` with precisely the environment set by the ENVVAR=value options.

The third mode - amending the environment - is less important because you can do that fine with regular (civilized) shells.  (That means "not C shell" - again, there are other questions on SO with answers that explain that.)  For example, you could perfectly well do:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=${PREPENDPATH:?}:$PATH
exec python "$@"
```

This insists that `$PREPENDPATH` is set to a non-empty string in the environment, and then prepends it to `$PATH`, and exports the new PATH setting.  Then, using that new PATH, it executes the `python` program with the relevant arguments.  The `exec` replaces the shell script with `python`.  Note that this is quite different from:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=${PREPENDPATH:?}:$PATH exec python "$@"
```

Superficially, this is the same.  However, this will execute the `python` found on the pre-existing PATH, albeit with the new value of PATH in the process's environment.  So, in the example, you'd end up executing Python from `/usr/bin` and not the one from `/home/pi/prepend/bin`.

In your situation, I would probably not use `env` and would just use an appropriate variant of the script with the explicit export.

The `env` command is unusual because it does not recognize the double-dash to separate options from the rest of the command.  This is in part because it does not take many options, and in part because it is not clear whether the ENVVAR=value options should come before or after the double dash.

I actually have a series of scripts for running (different versions of) a database server.  These scripts really use `env` (and a bunch of home-grown programs) to control the environment of the server:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#
# @(#)$Id: boot.black_19.sh,v 1.3 2008/06/25 15:44:44 jleffler Exp $
#
# Boot server black_19 - IDS 11.50.FC1

IXD=/usr/informix/11.50.FC1
IXS=black_19
cd $IXD || exit 1

IXF=$IXD/do.not.start.$IXS
if [ -f $IXF ]
then
    echo "$0: will not start server $IXS because file $IXF exists" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

ONINIT=$IXD/bin/oninit.$IXS
if [ ! -f $ONINIT ]
then ONINIT=$IXD/bin/oninit
fi

tmpdir=$IXD/tmp
DAEMONIZE=/work1/jleffler/bin/daemonize
stdout=$tmpdir/$IXS.stdout
stderr=$tmpdir/$IXS.stderr

if [ ! -d $tmpdir ]
then asroot -u informix -g informix -C -- mkdir -p $tmpdir
fi

# Specialized programs carried to extremes:
#   * asroot sets UID and GID values and then executes
#   * env, which sets the environment precisely and then executes
#   * daemonize, which makes the process into a daemon and then executes
#   * oninit, which is what we really wanted to run in the first place!
# NB: daemonize defaults stdin to /dev/null and could set umask but
#     oninit dinks with it all the time so there is no real point.
# NB: daemonize should not be necessary, but oninit doesn't close its
#     controlling terminal and therefore causes cron-jobs that restart
#     it to hang, and interactive shells that started it to hang, and
#     tracing programs.
# ??? Anyone want to integrate truss into this sequence?

asroot -u informix -g informix -C -a dbaao -a dbsso -- \
    env -i HOME=$IXD \
        INFORMIXDIR=$IXD \
        INFORMIXSERVER=$IXS \
        INFORMIXCONCSMCFG=$IXD/etc/concsm.$IXS \
        IFX_LISTEN_TIMEOUT=3 \
        ONCONFIG=onconfig.$IXS \
        PATH=/usr/bin:$IXD/bin \
        SHELL=/usr/bin/ksh \
        TZ=UTC0 \
    $DAEMONIZE -act -d $IXD -o $stdout -e $stderr -- \
    $ONINIT "$@"

case "$*" in
(*v*) track-oninit-v $stdout;;
esac
```

Comment: This is useful information, but as the OP says, his/her kernel won't run non-binaries (such as the bash stubs you provide) as the first element of a shebang line. Mine won't either; specifically, the kernel silently fails to run the script with the problematic shebang line in the desired (non-binary) interpreter, and then my shell will try to run the script instead. (My understading is that this is an old-time shell behavior which many shells retain.)

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying?  Are you claiming that there are (still) shells or kernels that won't handle `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/ksh` as the first line of a script?  I'm not claiming or showing that you can use `#!/some/script` as a shebang.

Comment: Not claiming the first. The OP's question is about the second, though: he/she asked "What does the kernel do if you stick a shell-script into the shebang line?" and then reports problems that come from using env.1 as a shebang line, where env.1 is a script. (As it happens, it was searching for discussions of limitations about shebang lines that brought me here. And I did find your post had useful information, so thanks for contributing it. I was just pointing out, for other readers who may come later, that what you discuss doesn't help overcome the limitation the OP had come up against.)

Answer (score 4):

You should carefully read the wikipedia article about [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

When your system sees the magic number corresponding to the shebang, it does an `execve` on the given path after the shebang and gives the script itself as an argument.

Your script fails because the file you give (`/usr/bin/env.1`) is not *an executable*, but begins itself by a shebang....

Ideally, you could resolve it using... `env` on your script with this line as a shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /usr/bin/env.1 python
```

It won't work though on linux as it treats "`/usr/bin/env.1 python`" as a path (it doesn't split arguments)

So the only way I see is to write your `env.1` in C

EDIT: seems like no one belives me ^^, so I've written a simple and dirty `env.1.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


const  char* prependpath = "/your/prepend/path/here:";

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  int args_len = argc + 1;
  char* args[args_len];
  const char* env = "/usr/bin/env";
  int i;

  /* arguments: the same */
  args[0] = env;
  for(i=1; i<argc; i++)
    args[i] = argv[i];
  args[argc] = NULL;

  /* environment */
  char* p = getenv("PATH");
  char* newpath = (char*) malloc(strlen(p)
                 + strlen(prependpath));
  sprintf(newpath, "%s%s", prependpath, p);
  setenv("PATH", newpath, 1);

  execv(env, args);
  return 0;
}
```