# Executing an Expect script from different locations

Tags: linux, shell, automation, clearcase, expect

I am trying to run my Expect script from two different locations and it will work with the following Expect executables referenced:

1. My linux home directory (`#!/usr/bin/expect`)
2. A clearcase view on another server (`#!/clearlib/vobs/otherdir/bin/expect`)

The problem is that I cannot run the script in both places unless I change the reference of the Expect executable location to the first line of the file.

How can I get the correct instance of the Expect executable for the corresponding directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your path is correctly set on both servers, you could use [`/usr/bin/env`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env):

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
```

That would use the expect as found in the `PATH` (`/usr/bin` in one case, `/clearlib/vobs/otherdir/bin` in the other)

> By instead using `env` as in the example, the interpreter is searched for and located at the time the script is run.
>   This makes the script more portable, but also increases the risk that the wrong interpreter is selected because it searches for a match in every directory on the executable search path.
>   It also suffers from the same problem in that the path to the `env` binary may also be different on a per-machine basis.

And if you have issue with setting the right `PATH`, then "[`/usr/bin/env` questions regarding shebang line pecularities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352532/usr-bin-env-questions-regarding-shebang-line-pecularities)" can help.

Comment: Wow that was very simple. Thanks again Von!